# How to use weights from our data set properly? Should we use them at all?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, census

The census data set I'm using: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

So, I'm currently using this census data to make observations and predict whether someone is married or not. However, when I plot a categorical graph for the race, it's overwhelmingly white and I was going to just not take race into account at all. Before I did that, though, I realized that I didn't take into account the "final weights" in the data set, which shows the number of people the census believes that the entry represents.

So, I have a few questions:

Should I use these weights when making observations? Am I interpreting this correctly? Or should I just ignore them?

If I were to use these weights, how exactly would I go about using these weights? I want to be able to predict whether someone is married or not based on a few of these factors given, but I'm having trouble figuring out how I should incorporate these weights.

Also, would it be dumb to divide all the final weights by 100 or something similar? All of these weights are in the hundreds of thousands, and I was thinking that if we divide the weights by some constant, then we can just add that number of rows (for each row based on its weight) to our data set.

I'm new to ML in general so forgive me if this is a newbie question.

Comment: Usually the US Census is very good at documenting how it performed its sampling, how it developed its weights, and how to interpret them.  In some cases at least it even offers software for processing the weights correctly.  Have you investigated those Census metadata?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! And yes I have. The "final weight" column is essentially how many people that the U.S. Census believes that entry represents. 


So, for example, if a White American with an Occupation in Tech makes more than 50K and has a final weight of about 200,000, then it would mean that the U.S. Census believes that there are 200,000 white americans in tech who make more than 50k.